# Get the Firefox Default Profile

Tags: python, python-3.x

To get the Firefox default profile, I am using the following program.

```
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import re

x = glob.glob(str(Path.home()) + '/.mozilla/firefox/*/')
r = re.compile(".*default-release.*")
firefox_default_profile = list(filter(r.match, x))[0]
print(firefox_default_profile)
```

The logic is simple. The path looks like `~/.mozilla/firefox/5ierwkox.default-release`.

In the whole path the only variable is the `5ierwkox`. It varies from person to person.

The program works fine, but I am wondering if I have over-complicated the code or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the Firefox default profile"? The full path to the folder it is in? Or something else? Can you [clarify](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/268770/edit)? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/268770/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- You don't need to import `glob`; `pathlib.Path` has a [`Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) method.
- You don't need to import `re`; you can merge the regex into the glob - `.*default-release.*` become `*default-release*`.
- You can use `next(...)` rather than `list(...)[0]`.
- By passing `None` as a second argument to `next` we can prevent the code from erroring if the user doesn't have a Firefox profile.

```py
import pathlib

profiles = pathlib.Path.home().glob(".mozilla/firefox/*default-release*/")
firefox_default_profile = next(profiles, None)
print(firefox_default_profile)
```

Comment: Note.  This returns a `Path` object instead of a `str`.  (And it will return `None` instead of raising an exception if the default profile cannot be found.)

Comment: @AJNeufeld You are certainly correct. Depending on what Python version one is running may mean the code no-longer works as expected. Requiring a call to `str` before being passed to some functions.

Answer (score 2):

None of my profiles have `default-release` in the name.

To find the default profile, we need to parse `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini` and find the section with `Default=1` set.

Comment: "[If you only have one profile, its folder would have "default" in the name.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data)" - Mozilla docs. Seems the glob/regex is also wrong and should be `*default*`. Do you have multiple profiles, which has caused the 'default' one to disappear?

Comment: One of my profiles ends in `.default`, but doesn't contain `-release`.  The other has neither; I can see it's possible for the initial default to be deleted, leaving none with `default` in the name.  Or for the user's default to be one that's not named with `default` in it.

Comment: You brought up an important point. I did not know about `profiles.ini`. I could just get the profile I want from this file. No, glob was needed. However, The accepted answer is according to my question and it works for me. And if I try to modify the question then it will be an injustice to the accepted answer. So, I think it will be better if someone could point out the gap in my question and give an appropriate answer.

Comment: For the issue you pointed out, I think using [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) will be a better way to go.

Comment: You're right - don't modify your question (CR doesn't like edits that invalidate answers).  However, you can take advice from both answers, and write a new question if you want your resulting improved code to be reviewed.